# Is there any way to resolve runtime error in this code?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python.I don't understand why this code is showing me Runtime error.

```
def performOperations(arr,element):
    if element in arr:
        arr[0],arr[-1]=arr[-1],arr[0]
    else:
        arr[-1]=element
    return arr
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N,M = map(int,input().split())
    arr=list(range(1,N+1))
    for i in range(M):
        element=int(input())
        result=performOperations(arr,element)
        print(sum(result))
```

Comment: Exactly what error are you getting, and what line of your code does the error message indicate?

Comment: We don't understand why this code is showing you Runtime error, either. Please [edit] your question to *show us* the RuntimeError. Take a look at the [mcve] and [ask] pages how to best help us help you.

Comment: I don't understand why it is showing runtime error.

Comment: Again, *we cannot see the runtime error*. You must [edit] your question and *show it to us* as well.